# input value in one column if values in another are the first instance above a new floor.math integer

Tags: excel

I have two columns in Excel. I would like to populate col1 with number 25 if in col2 it is greater than 80000. But, I only want the number 25 to appear the first time the value in col2 is g>= than a multiple 80000. Lastly, the number 25 should appear again the first time a value in col2 is >=160000...and so on.

```
VALUE   expected output
1,631   
39,716  
85,022  25
123,192 
151,744 
173,125 25
190,520 
205,108 
217,553 
228,323 
237,753 
254,024 25
299,957 
331,953 25
354,286 
333,296 
297,460
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B2:

```
=IF(INT(A2/80000)>0,IF(INT(A2/80000)<>INT(A1/80000),25,""),"")
```

and copy down

[image]